# How to create two LicenseFile pages in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, licensing

I'm making an Inno setup for my application. I'm using this command:

```
[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"; LicenseFile: "C:\Users\LocDaiLe\Desktop\license.txt"
```

to display a license agreement window, but I want two license agreement window right after each others. How can I archieve this - thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to code the second license page as a [custom page](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptpages).

You can start with the [`CreateOutputMsgMemoPage` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_createoutputmsgmemopage), which creates a page with a memo. Then, you just add radio buttons for accepting the license.

```
[Files]
; Embed the second license files
; (the part after underscore must match the Name parameter from Languages section)
Source: "license2_english.txt"; Flags: dontcopy
Source: "license2_czech.txt"; Flags: dontcopy
; Other languages
```

```pascal
[Code]

var
  SecondLicensePage: TOutputMsgMemoWizardPage;
  License2AcceptedRadio: TRadioButton;
  License2NotAcceptedRadio: TRadioButton;

procedure CheckLicense2Accepted(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // Update Next button when user (un)accepts the license
  WizardForm.NextButton.Enabled := License2AcceptedRadio.Checked;
end;

function CloneLicenseRadioButton(Source: TRadioButton): TRadioButton;
begin
  Result := TRadioButton.Create(WizardForm);
  Result.Parent := SecondLicensePage.Surface;
  Result.Caption := Source.Caption;
  Result.Left := Source.Left;
  Result.Top := Source.Top;
  Result.Width := Source.Width;
  Result.Height := Source.Height;
  // Needed for WizardStyle=modern / WizardResizable=yes
  Result.Anchors := Source.Anchors;
  Result.OnClick := @CheckLicense2Accepted;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard();
var
  LicenseFileName: string;
  LicenseFilePath: string;
begin
  // Create second license page, with the same labels as the original license page
  SecondLicensePage :=
    CreateOutputMsgMemoPage(
      wpLicense, SetupMessage(msgWizardLicense), SetupMessage(msgLicenseLabel),
      SetupMessage(msgLicenseLabel3), '');

  // Shrink license box to make space for radio buttons
  SecondLicensePage.RichEditViewer.Height := WizardForm.LicenseMemo.Height;

  // Load license
  // Loading ex-post, as Lines.LoadFromFile supports UTF-8,
  // contrary to LoadStringFromFile.
  LicenseFileName := 'license2_' + ActiveLanguage + '.txt';
  ExtractTemporaryFile(LicenseFileName);
  LicenseFilePath := ExpandConstant('{tmp}\' + LicenseFileName);
  SecondLicensePage.RichEditViewer.Lines.LoadFromFile(LicenseFilePath);
  DeleteFile(LicenseFilePath);

  // Clone accept/do not accept radio buttons for the second license
  License2AcceptedRadio :=
    CloneLicenseRadioButton(WizardForm.LicenseAcceptedRadio);
  License2NotAcceptedRadio :=
    CloneLicenseRadioButton(WizardForm.LicenseNotAcceptedRadio);

  // Initially not accepted
  License2NotAcceptedRadio.Checked := True;
end;

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  // Update Next button when user gets to second license page
  if CurPageID = SecondLicensePage.ID then
  begin
    CheckLicense2Accepted(nil);
  end;
end;
```

---

For a generalization of the solution that allows adding any number of license pages, see:
[Inno Setup - Add 4 license pages](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74264733/850848)

---

Original (first) license page:

[image: License 1]

Coded (second) license page:

[image: License 2]

Answer (score 2):

I also had to display two license files, but I did it by adding these two lines to the setup sectiony:

```
LicenseFile={#MyFileSource}License.rtf
InfoBeforeFile={#MyFileSource}License2.rtf
```

Works like a charm for me

Comment: It's do presents the second file but the "I accept" part is missing