# Inno Setup - InfoBeforeFile page before License page

Tags: inno-setup

By default, the page showing `InfoBeforeFile` file is shown after the license page. From reading the documentation I should be able to re-arrange when these pages are displayed but I don't see how the ordered is structured in Inno setup scripts or the default.isl. This is all under the `[Setup]` section.

I am simply trying to move the `InfoBeforeFile` page to be displayed before displaying the license page.

Any help or direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After review of the two setup help and documentation, I've found the solution.

**Summary:** Basically, what this does is clone the page of Information Page and uses the language variables from that page (`WizardInfoBefore`) and when the page is created with `CreateOutputMsgMemoPage` it is set as a 'Welcome Page' with the first parameter of `wpWelcome`.

1. You must a define, a welcome page text

   ```
   #define WelcomeFile 'welcome.rtf'
   ```
2. Define your normal license file under the `[Setup]` section:

   ```
   LicenseFile=gnu.rtf
   ```
3. Include the following line in `[Files]` section:

   ```
   Source: "{#WelcomeFile}"; Flags: dontcopy
   ```
4. Include the following lines in the `[Code]` section:

   ```pascal
   [Code]
   var
     WelcomePage: TOutputMsgMemoWizardPage;

   procedure InitializeWizard();
   var
     WelcomeFileName: string;
     WelcomeFilePath: string;
   begin
     { Create welcome page, with the same labels as the information page }
     WelcomePage :=
       CreateOutputMsgMemoPage(
         wpWelcome, SetupMessage(msgWizardInfoBefore), SetupMessage(msgInfoBeforeLabel),
         SetupMessage(msgInfoBeforeClickLabel), '');

     { Load welcome page }
     WelcomeFileName := '{#WelcomeFile}';
     ExtractTemporaryFile(WelcomeFileName);
     WelcomeFilePath := ExpandConstant('{tmp}\' + WelcomeFileName);
     WelcomePage.RichEditViewer.Lines.LoadFromFile(WelcomeFilePath);
     DeleteFile(WelcomeFilePath);
   end;
   ```

Output:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You cannot reorder the standard pages.

Your might be able to code a different order by cleverly implementing [`NextButtonClick`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=NextButtonClick), [`BackButtonClick`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=BackButtonClick), [`CurPageChanged`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CurPageChanged) and [`ShouldSkipPage`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=ShouldSkipPage) event functions. But that would be too complicated. You would have to re-implement lot of built in functionality of Inno Setup.

---

A way easier is to insert a custom license page or info page in the order you want.

This example adds a custom license page:
[How to create two LicenseFile pages in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34592002/850848).
Actually adding a custom info page is 
a lot easier, as it does not have the radio buttons. All you need is to load a file to a page created with [`CreateOutputMsgMemoPage` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_createoutputmsgmemopage).