# Inno Setup - Display message if "I Do Not Accept" radio button is selected

Tags: installation, inno-setup, pascalscript

I am using a variation of [How to create two LicenseFile pages in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34592002/how-to-create-two-licensefile-pages-in-inno-setup) to display a second license page in an Inno Setup-based installer. Unlike that code, I am not selecting a default. So these radio buttons appear, with no selection:

```
[ ] I accept the agreement
[ ] I do not accept the agreement
```

If the user selects the second radio -- *I do not accept the agreement* -- I would like to show a custom message to the user (message window). I do not need it to allow *Next>* to be clicked still or other workflow. Just show a message when they click do not accept radio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle the `OnClick` event (despite the naming, it's triggered when the radio button is selected any way):

```pascal
procedure License2NotAcceptedRadioClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MsgBox('Hello.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
end;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  { ... }

  License2NotAcceptedRadio.OnClick := @License2NotAcceptedRadioClick;
end;
```

*As Bill commented, you should handle silent installations somehow.*

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you Martin.